# How to start mono-service by Python?

Tags: python, mono

I have a bash shell like this:

```
server_home=`pwd`
kill `cat $server_home'/AppService.pid'`
if [ -f $server_home/AppService.pid ]; then
    rm $server_home/AppService.pid
fi
export MONO_PATH=$server_home"/bin:"$server_home"/Function"
mono-service2 -l:$server_home/AppService.pid $server_home/bin/AppService.exe
```

It can start the mono service. And now I need do a little more work, so I write a python shell like this :

```
import os
server_home=os.getcwd()
tmpPID = server_home +'/AppService.pid'
tmpSS = server_home + '/bin/AppService.exe'
os.popen("kill `cat '" + tmpPID +"'`").close()
if os.path.isfile(tmpPID):
    print "start delete pid"
    os.remove(tmpPID)
else:
    print "cant find the " + tmpPID

print  'mono-service2 -l:'+tmpPID+' '+tmpSS
output = os.popen('mono-service2 -l:'+tmpPID+' '+tmpSS)
print output.read()
output.close()
```

It will delete the AppService.PID file but wouldn't start the service.What is wrong with my code? Please help me. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

The use of `os.popen` is [deprecated](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html?highlight=popen#os.popen). Have you tried using [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html?highlight=subprocess#using-the-subprocess-module)?

```
subprocess.call(["mono-service2", "-l:" + tmpPID, tmpSS])
```